# How to get contact by phone number?

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

How to get contact (`Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact`) by phone number using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get contacts for this with [ContactStore.FindContactsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/dn624861.aspx) and then parse them for example with linq. As it is said at MSDN you can search contacts by passing a number, but as I've tried, you will have to put the whole number. So if you want to search for all contacts for example containing '199', you should be able to do this like this:

```
var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var contacts = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();
var contactsByNumber = contacts.Where(x => x.Phones.Any(y => y.Number.Contains("199")));
//var contactsByNumber = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync("112"); // you may search like this but you must enter full number
foreach (var item in contactsByNumber) Debug.WriteLine($"Name: {item.DisplayName} Phone: {item.Phones.FirstOrDefault().Number}");
```

Remember to add *Contacts* capability in manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Use this :)

```
private async Task<Contact> SearchContactByPhoneNumberAsync(string phoneNumber)
{
    Contact resultContact = null;
    var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AllContactsReadOnly);
    var contactReader = contactStore.GetContactReader(new ContactQueryOptions(phoneNumber));
    while (true)
    {
        var contactBatch = await contactReader.ReadBatchAsync();
        if (contactBatch.Contacts.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var contact in contactBatch.Contacts)
            {
                if (contact.Phones?.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var phone in contact.Phones)
                    {
                        if (phone.Number == phoneNumber)
                        {
                            resultContact = contact;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return resultContact;
}
```

I've created a test contact with number `0635806354` and searched using code bellow:

```
    var result = await SearchContactByPhoneNumberAsync("+38 (063) 580-63-54");
    if (result != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(result.Name);
    }
```